# How to update web page without refreshing (Angular 6 CLI)?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, angular6, hot-module-replacement

I don't need ng serve, only nb build because it's a .net core app and I use only static files.

I used `ng build --watch` but after each code update I need to refresh the page to saw new changes. I saw another method with `ng serve -hmr` but like I said I don't use that.

It's a way to update in real time code without refreshing. I need the same flow like in webpack with hot module.

Comment: Check the last comment on this issue, maybe its the same as yours? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4329

Comment: it's not, I don't need ng serve... only ng build

Comment: set the mission control and watch your project when modified in `.net`.